# Showing Calluptree of Functionpointers in C

Tags: c, eclipse, macros, call, function-pointers

While trying to understand and refacturing some C-Code I would like to show some callgraphs including functioncalls via macros or functionpointers.

What I already tested:

- **Eclipse Calluphierachy (CTRL+ALT+H):** Those Callgraphs  include just normal Function-Calls. Dynamically Function-Calls via
  Functionpointers are not shown. Even Functioncalls which are
  implemented through Macros with a #define are not shown. So this is
  not enough.
- **Eclipse Show Reference (SHIFT+CTRL+G):** Those References show just
  simple usages. There is no tree, just the incident are listed.
- **Understand from scitools:** This IDE can show graphical Calluptrees, but it doesn't show macros or
  functionpointers.
- **Doxygen:** Can show beatiful Callgraphs, but it doesn't show macros or
  functionpointers.

So does anybody know how to show callupgraphs containing also Function-Macros and Function-Pointers?

Comment: You cannot know callgraph of function pointers because they are assigned at runtime.

Comment: Thats true. But if a function pointer is initialized in sourcecode, it is known  at compiletime which functions could be called through this pointer.  So those calles could be viewd as "possible calls".